# How to load assets from smart album? (expo-media-library)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Is there a way to load assets from smart album (on iOS) using expo-media-library?

I've tried to load assets by following instructions from documentation (Selfies is a name of smart album):

```
const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Selfies');
const response = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({ album });
```

But it seems that this approach only works for user-created folders/albums (for smart albums it returns data for All photos)

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this issue while working on expo. Here how solved this issue..
Using MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync(); you will get all list of albums, from that list choose album name or id of that album and pass this album id to MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync(); it will load all assets from that particular album.